# Youtube-dl cannot read various set on batch script

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I created an batch-script that positioned with youtube-dl and ffmpeg. I set several set to put URL and Video/Audio ID. Here my script that I simplified

```
@echo off
cd /d %root%\YT
color 0a
title Youtube Downloader
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set q=^"
color 0a

:submenu
echo Please enter URL.
set /p f1="URL: " 
echo Checking ID...
youtube-dl -F %f1%
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
goto menu

:menu
echo.
echo Script created by UrbaseR
echo ___________________________________________________________
echo.
echo                          MENU
echo ___________________________________________________________
echo OS Windows - %ComputerName%
echo.
echo M E N U
echo Press 1 to Download Best version 
echo Press 2 to Download Custom version + convert
echo Press 3 to Exit

set /p you=">"
if %you%==1 goto 1
if %you%==2 goto 2
if %you%==3 goto 3

cls
echo *********************************
echo Sorry invalid number!
echo *********************************
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
goto menu

:1
echo Downloading...
youtube-dl -f best %f1%
echo.
echo Done
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
goto submenu

:2
set /p id1="Insert Video ID: "
set /p id2="Insert Audio ID: "
echo Downloading Video..
youtube-dl -f %id1% -ciw -o "vid.%(ext)s" -v --write-sub %f1%
echo.
echo Video Done
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
echo Downloading Audio..
youtube-dl -f %id2% -ciw -o "aud.%(ext)s" -v %f1%
echo.
echo Audio Done
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
echo Converting Video
ffmpeg -i "vid.%(ext)s" -i "aud.%(ext)s" -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental "input.mkv"
echo Converting Done
ping localhost -n 4 >nul
cls
goto submenu

:3
exit
```

First and third option execute successfully. Second option will appear the message like this:

> Usage: youtube-dl [OPTIONS] URL [URL...]
> youtube-dl: error: You must provide at least one URL.
>
> Type youtube-dl --help to see a list of all options.

Note: Since I stuck on first and second stage of youtube-dl, ffmpeg may not work (I have not tested it yet).

Can you help me?

Comment: and then what happened when you typed `youtube-dl --help` like the error suggested you do? `:)` It seems to me that you have the URL in the wrong place. if you are able to get a result when running `echo %f1%` in the script, the URL is valid and you just need to fix your string. `youtube-dl.exe --write-sub -o "vid.%(ext)s" " %f1%`

Comment: thx  to you, i echo the line and got the problem started with ` -o "vid.%(ext)s" ` which contain special character that mess the line. (sorry i forgot to echo line in first place)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After re-fix the script is pretty much done.

```
@echo off
cd /d %root%\YT
color 0a
title Youtube Downloader
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set q=^"
color 0a

:submenu
echo Please enter URL.
set /p f1="URL: " 
cls
echo Checking ID...
youtube-dl -F %f1%
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
goto menu

:menu
echo.
echo.
echo Script created by UrbaseR
echo ___________________________________________________________
echo.
echo                          MENU
echo ___________________________________________________________
echo OS Windows - %ComputerName%
echo.
echo M E N U
echo Press 1 to Download Best version (default ver)
echo Press 2 to Download Custom version + Convert
echo Press 3 to Exit
echo.
echo URL: %f1%

set /p you=">"
if %you%==1 goto 1
if %you%==2 goto 2
if %you%==3 goto 3

cls
echo *********************************
echo Sorry invalid number!
echo *********************************
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
goto menu

:1
echo Downloading...
youtube-dl -f best %f1%
echo.
echo Done
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
goto submenu

:2
set /p id1="Insert Video ID: "
set /p id2="Insert Audio ID: "
set ida="v.data"
set idb="a.data"
set "f2="
set "f3="
cls
echo Downloading Video..
youtube-dl -f %id1% -ciw --o %ida% -v --write-sub %f1%
echo.
echo Video Done
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
echo Downloading Audio..
youtube-dl -f %id2% -ciw -o %idb% -v %f1%
echo.
echo Audio Done
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
echo Note Default title is: input.mkv
echo.
set /p f2="Enter Video Title: "
if not defined f2 set "f2=input"
set /p f3="Format Video: "
if not defined f3 set "f3=mkv"
echo Converting Video..
ffmpeg -i %ida% -i %idb% -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental "%f2%.%f3%"
echo Converting Done
del /q %ida%
del /q %idb%
ping localhost -n 4 >nul
cls
goto submenu

:3
exit
```

Feel free to use the script.

Note: Be sure to have youtube-dl.exe and ffmpeg.exe on same folder, video will also saved on same folder .